# Matrix - Triangular Elimination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

Look for a matrix that has row sums 4 and 8 and column sums 2 and s:

Matrix = [a b]

```
       [c d]


    a+b=4
    c+d=8
    a+c=2
    b+d=s
```

The four equations are solvable only if s=?

Then, find two different matrices that have the correct row and column sums.

(I was able to solve the problem up to this part to find that s=10. The two examples I calculated are a=2, b=2, c=0, and d=8 for one matrix and a=1, b=3, c=1, and d=7 for the second matrix.)

Then, write down the 4 by 4 system Ax=b with x=(a,b,c,d) and make A triangular by elimination. (This is where I'm stuck. I'm not sure how to pick the order of the rows.)